# Angular Elements: How to pass a template to the component?

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I built an Angular component that displays an array of markers on a map. When one of these markers gets clicked a popup will be displayed. The content of this popup can be defined by the user of my component.

I solved this by accepting an `ng-template` as `@Input` parameter.

```
<my-map
  [markers]="markers"
  [popupTemplate]="popupTemplate">
</my-map>

<ng-template #popupTemplate let-marker>
  <h1>{{marker.title}}</h1>
  <div>{{marker.subtitle}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

This works fine! But now I am publishing this component as a Web Component using Angular Elements. How do I solve the templating part for the Web Component?

Answer (score 0):

I can not see the problem. well, generally you should define a "default template"

In you component, I suppose you has a *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let marker of markers">

    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template?template:defaultTemplate;
                        context:{$implicit:marker}" >
    </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #defaultTemplate let-marker>
  <h1>{{marker.title}}</h1>
  <div>{{marker.subtitle}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: The Web Component will be used in a non-Angular application. Which means I cannot simply define a ng-template and pass it to the component.

Comment: @Sebi did you ever find a solution to this? I'm evaluating using Angular Elements for a project and ended up with the exact same question without any luck finding an answer.

Comment: Either of you ( @JKasper11 ) find a solution?

Comment: @Charly Negative -- I found very few resources for Angular Elements and couldn't get any responses from the Discord so I ended up not using it.

Comment: @JKasper11 This saddens me. I've got a hacky solution I'll post to your question hopefully today as it fits over there more (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819490/how-do-you-create-web-components-with-customizable-templates-using-angular-eleme)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this may be to accept a template string and the component would need to know how to deal with it.

A function for handling template strings:

```
export const template = (str, vars): string => new Function(`return \`${ str.replace(/\${/g, '${this.') }\`;`).call(vars);
```

Essentially builds a function on the fly to treat a given string as if it were a `template ${string}`

Usage:

```
let myTemplate = 'Just a ${field}';
let vars       = { field: 'test' };
let str        = template(myTemplate, vars); // "Just a test"
```

**Option 1:**

The Angular component could accept a template string and perform this template against it, then feed it to the DOM sanitizer for safe HTML to be used as an `[innerHTML]`

Annoying, but an option.

**Option 2:**

Could accept it as content

```
<my-map [markers]="markers">
  <template>
    <h1>${marker.title}</h1>
    <div>${marker.subtitle}</div>
  </template>
</my-map>
```

Angular Elements doesn't support `ngContent` or `ngContentChildren` (doesn't convert them to `<slot>` or anything either), so this option would require fancy footwork on behalf of the Angular Component.

The component's template needs to spit out the given content, something like

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Somewhere in it's template so it'll render the given content.

Then in the component, grab the DOM contents to be templated. (probably after `ngOnInit`)

```
this.hackyTemplateHtml = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('template').innerHtml;
```

If requiring multiple templates, could have the implementation send them with a unique attribute or class `<template class='marker-template'>`

For the template loop, would need to send each marker to be templated:

```
<div *ngFor="let marker of markers; trackBy: trackByTitle">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="hackyTemplateHtml ? hackyTemplate : defaultTemplate;
                    context:{$implicit:marker}" >
  </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #defaultTemplate let-marker>
  <h1>{{marker.title}}</h1>
  <div>{{marker.subtitle}}</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #hackyTemplate let-marker>
  <div [outerHTML]="templateHacky(marker)"></div>
</ng-template>
```

The `ngFor` should probably implement a `trackBy` so it's not re-templating constantly. and the `[outerHTML]` is so it replaces the `<div>`, so it's not wrappered.

Back in the component:

```
trackByTitle(idx, marker) {
  return marker.title;
}

templateHacky(marker: Marker) {
  let templated = template(this.hackyTemplateHtml, { marker });
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(templated);
}
```

Also definitely hacky. Best I could think of as plain HTML/JS implementation.
I'm working on a solution for react/vue to be able to send the equivalent of an Angular `TemplateRef` to Angular Elements to be treated as a normal template. Needs further thinking of how to do it frameworkless though.